# Why can't I install nmap?

Tags: debian, apt

```
root@R2CPU:/# sudo apt-get install nmap
sudo: unable to resolve host R2CPU: Connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libblas-common libblas3 libgfortran3 liblinear3 liblua5.3-0 libpython-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libxslt1.1 ndiff python python-bs4
  python-chardet python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal
  python-pkg-resources python-six python-webencodings python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  liblinear-tools liblinear-dev python-doc python-tk python-genshi
  python-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc python-setuptools python2.7-doc
  binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libblas-common libblas3 libgfortran3 liblinear3 liblua5.3-0 libpython-stdlib
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libxslt1.1 ndiff nmap python
  python-bs4 python-chardet python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal
  python-pkg-resources python-six python-webencodings python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 217 kB/11.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 43.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main armhf libxslt1.1 armhf 1.1.29-2.1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxslt/libxslt1.1_1.1.29-2.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root@R2CPU:/# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs           87000       0     87000   0% /dev
/dev/mmcblk1p2   3096336 1531440   1407612  53% /
tmpfs             254532       0    254532   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             254532    6976    247556   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             254532       0    254532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs              50904       0     50904   0% /run/user/0
root@R2CPU:/#
```

I do not understand  `E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxslt/libxslt1.1_1.1.29-2.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found`. Why does this not work?

I am using Debian 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your indexes first:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

The `libxslt1.1` package has been updated, the repository now contains version 1.1.29-2.1+deb9u1, and the version listed in your index (1.1.29-2.1) is no longer available.

See the last line in the output you quote:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```